# Mysql german accents not-sensitive search in full-text searches

Tags: mysql, encoding, full-text-search, collation, diacritics

Let`s have a example hotels table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
  `HotelNo` varchar(4) character set latin1 NOT NULL default '0000',
  `Hotel` varchar(80) character set latin1 NOT NULL default '',
  `City` varchar(100) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `CityFR` varchar(100) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `RegionFR` varchar(100) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `CountryFR` varchar(50) character set latin1 default NULL,
  `HotelText` text character set latin1,
  `HotelTextFR` text character set latin1,
  `tagsforsearch` text character set latin1,
  `tagsforsearchFR` text character set latin1,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`HotelNo`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltextHotelSearch` (`HotelNo`,`Hotel`,`City`,`CityFR`,`Region`,`RegionFR`,`Country`,`CountryFR`,`HotelText`,`HotelTextFR`,`tagsforsearch`,`tagsforsearchFR`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci;
```

In this table for example we have only one hotel with Region name = "Graubünden" (please note umlaut ü character)

And now I want to achieve same search match for phrases:
'graubunden' and 
'graubünden'

This is simple with use of MySql built in 
collations in regular searches as follows:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `hotels` 
WHERE `Region` LIKE CONVERT(_utf8 '%graubunden%' USING latin1) 
COLLATE latin1_german1_ci
```

This works fine for 'graubunden' and 'graubünden' and 
as a result I receive proper result, but problem is 
when we make MySQL full text search

Whats wrong with this SQL statement?:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
 hotels 
WHERE 
 MATCH (`HotelNo`,`Hotel`,`Address`,`City`,`CityFR`,`Region`,`RegionFR`,`Country`,`CountryFR`, `HotelText`, `HotelTextFR`, `tagsforsearch`, `tagsforsearchFR`)
AGAINST( CONVERT('+graubunden' USING latin1)  COLLATE latin1_german1_ci IN BOOLEAN MODE)            
ORDER BY Country ASC, Region ASC, City ASC
```

This doesn`t return any result. 
Any ideas where the dog is buried ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define individual `CHARACTER SETS` for your columns, you override the collation you set default on table level.

Each of your columns has default `latin1` collation (which is `latin1_swedish_ci`). You can see it by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

In `FULLTEXT` queries, indexed columns have `COERCIBILITY` of `0`, that is all fulltext queries are converted to the collation used in the index, not vice versa.

You need to remove `CHARACTER SET` definitions from your columns or explicitly set all columns to `latin1_german_ci`:

```
CREATE TABLE `hotels` (
  `HotelNo` varchar(4) NOT NULL default '0000',
  `Hotel` varchar(80) NOT NULL default '',
  `City` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `CityFR` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `RegionFR` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `Country` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `CountryFR` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `HotelText` text,
  `HotelTextFR` text,
  `tagsforsearch` text,
  `tagsforsearchFR` text,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`HotelNo`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `fulltextHotelSearch` (`HotelNo`,`Hotel`,`City`,`CityFR`,`Region`,`RegionFR`,`Country`,`CountryFR`,`HotelText`,`HotelTextFR`,`tagsforsearch`,`tagsforsearchFR`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_german1_ci;

INSERT
INTO    hotels (hotelText, HotelTextFR, tagsforsearch, tagsforsearchFR)
VALUES  ('text', 'text', 'graubünden', 'tags');

SELECT  *
FROM    hotels
WHERE   MATCH (`HotelNo`,`Hotel`,`City`,`CityFR`,`Region`,`RegionFR`,`Country`,`CountryFR`, `HotelText`, `HotelTextFR`, `tagsforsearch`, `tagsforsearchFR`)
AGAINST (CONVERT('+graubunden' USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_german1_ci IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY
        Country ASC, Region ASC, City ASC;
```

Comment: That is 100% true. Thank you very much!