# How to make MediaWiki search ignore accents?

Tags: mediawiki

I'm running a MediaWiki instance that I just upgraded to the latest version at the time of this writing, 1.32.0. This wiki is nearly 10 years old and has gone through a number of upgrades.

It's a wiki in French language, and something annoying for French speakers is that **the built-in search has always considered accented characters different from their non-accented counterparts**, version after version.

For example, searching for `Aromathérapie` returns a number of results, while searching for `Aromatherapie` returns 0 results.

I thought that this was a database collation issue at first, until I noticed that the `searchindex` table is actually populated with ASCII-encoded UTF-8 words. Taking the example above, `aromathérapie` is stored as `aromathu8c3a9rapie`, so changing the table collation does not help.

Digging through the source code, I found the [SearchMySQL::normalizeText()](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/1.32.0/includes/search/SearchMySQL.php#L388) method that is responsible for this encoding.

And as far as I can see, the only normalization that this method does prior to encoding is lowercasing:

```
MediaWikiServices::getInstance()->getContentLanguage()->lc( $out )
```

So as it stands, it looks like there is no way to make the built-in search ignore accents.

I googled quite a lot for solutions, and found mostly old, unrelevant threads. I'm really surprised to not find more literature on the subject.

**How can I make the MediaWiki search case- AND accents- insensitive?**

Comment: The built-in MySQL search is not very powerful; you might want to install a search extension, e.g. [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch).

Comment: I was hoping I could leverage MySQL's excellent support for collations (at least in recent versions), instead of having to install 2 MediaWiki extensions + 1 third party software. But I'm afraid you're right: it looks like there is no effort on MediaWiki's side to support this, and I'm not sure I want to fiddle with the code and go through the maintenance hell of future upgrades.

Comment: @Benjamin My MediaWiki 1.31 Install works by default. I have an article called `René` and can find it through searching `Rene`. Is it possible that the only reason you couldn't is because the method of indexing them has changed since the version of MediaWiki where your articles were created? Did you try creating a new article and seeing if there was a problem?

Comment: @Benjamin I assume none of the stuff at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014167/how-to-do-an-accent-and-case-insensitive-search-in-mediawiki-database?rq=1 worked for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not proud of it, but here's how I solved it, using MySQL's built-in support for collations (which *does* work with fulltext indexes—at least in recent versions of MySQL—contrary to what the code says):

- Converted the `searchindex` table to `utf8mb4`:
  `ALTER TABLE searchindex CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`
- Applied [this patch](https://gist.github.com/BenMorel/124231ba8f80f1528921c085ea2517d6/revisions) to `includes/search/SearchMySQL.php`:

  - no lowercasing, no replacing of UTF-8 chars with their hex-encoded counterpart
  - unicode `u` flag in `preg_replace()`
- Rebuilt the `searchindex` table:
  `php maintenance/rebuildtextindex.php`

A similar procedure will have to be applied whenever the MediaWiki installation is updated, which adds to the maintenance cost. The procedure being simple, it's a cost I'm willing to accept right now.

A final note is that this does not make the autocompletion work case-insensitively, only the search results. This is good enough for me for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch), you could try a lightweight extension:
[TitleKey](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3ATitleKey)

**Installation**

- [Download](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ExtensionDistributor/TitleKey) and place the file(s) in a directory called TitleKey in your extensions/ folder.
- Add the following code at the bottom of your `LocalSettings.php`:

  ```
  wfLoadExtension( 'TitleKey' );
  ```
- Run the update script which will automatically create the necessary database tables that this extension needs.
- Run the `rebuildTitleKeys.php` script (this requires command-line access):

  ```
  php extensions/TitleKey/rebuildTitleKeys.php
  ```
- Done – Navigate to `Special:Version` on your wiki to verify that the extension is successfully installed.

Comment: I followed every step here, the installation went smoothly, update & rebuild scripts OK, the Special:Version page shows the TitleKey extension as installed,but unfortunately the search is still case sensitive: searching for `aromathérapie` returns results, while `aromatherapie` does not. Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry. I assumed that the extension would cover your problem, But it seems this is just a feature request: https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T22097

Answer (score -1):

Lets tackle each problem one at a time.

First lets handle the smaller problem, case sensitivity

`select * from tableName where lower(col_name) = lower(searchTerm);`

or

`select * from tableName where upper(col_name) = upper(searchTerm);`

Part 2 handling the encoding, as suggested by others, you can download a more competent search tool, or you can change how your search term is represented, convert

`searchTerm` to `%s%e%a%r%c%h%T%e%r%m%`. This will basically add wildcards capable of ignoring extra characters added by UTF-8 encoding. The advantage of this approach is you have to make minimal changes to your existing code, but it slightly increases the computation and complexity.

This was written in the context of SQL, if you are using other database management, queries may slightly vary but the idea remains the same.

That should get the job done. If any questions feel free to add comments.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I know how to handle case insensitive searches if I'm writing the code myself (this is better handled using [collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html), by the way); my question is how to make MediaWiki handle searches in a case-insensitive manner, *without fiddling with the code myself*, for the reasons stated above. Your answer is therefore out of scope I'm afraid!

Comment: @Benjamin Ah that makes sense, sorry couldn't be of help.